# why my django url conf failed to include another apps url module

Tags: python, django

I have a project whose root url conf content is :

```
 from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
import funnytest
urlpatterns = patterns(
url(r'^funnytest/', include('funnytest.urls')),
url(r'^helloworld/', funnytest.views.hello),
)
```

funnytest is an  app of this project ，In funnytest I write a module urls.py to configure request of this app :

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from views import *
urlpatterns = patterns(
url(r'^hello/$', hello),
)
```

AS I visit  localhost/funnytest/hello/ there return a dispath error which say that there has no such pattern

While I visit localhost/helloworld , it works well.

为什么呢，应该如何配置～

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you look at the definition of the patterns function:

```
def patterns(prefix, *args):
    pattern_list = []
    for t in args:
        if isinstance(t, (list, tuple)):
            t = url(prefix=prefix, *t)
        elif isinstance(t, RegexURLPattern):
            t.add_prefix(prefix)
        pattern_list.append(t)
    return pattern_list
```

You'll see that patterns takes an argument 'prefix' before the list of url patterns.

Try the following in both files: Add an empty string as the first argument to patterns.

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
import funnytest
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^funnytest/', include('funnytest.urls')),
    url(r'^helloworld/', funnytest.views.hello),
)

from django.conf.urls import patterns, include, url
from views import *
urlpatterns = patterns(
    '',
    url(r'^hello/$', hello),
)
```

Comment: Here is a better discussion regarding the view prefix argument: [Django Documentation, URL Dispatcher, The view prefix](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/http/urls/#the-view-prefix)